# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Interface can't be instantiated! Interface name: com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place

Tags: android, google-places-api, retrofit2

I am sending raw json in retrofit body. The json request object works fine in postman but with retrofit it throws exception.
This is my interface

```
public interface RetrofitApi {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/cook/list")
    Call<GetNearByCooks> getCooksNearBy(@Body String object);
}
```

This is model class

```
public class GetNearByCooks implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("status_code")
    @Expose
    private int status_code;

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<CookDetails> cookList;

    public GetNearByCooks(String status, int status_code, List<CookDetails> cookList) {
        this.status = status;
        this.status_code = status_code;
        this.cookList = cookList;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getStatus_code() {
        return status_code;
    }

    public void setStatus_code(int status_code) {
        this.status_code = status_code;
    }

    public List<CookDetails> getCookList() {
        return cookList;
    }

    public void setCookList(List<CookDetails> cookList) {
        this.cookList = cookList;
    }
}
```

This is CookDetails class

```
public class CookDetails implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    int id;

    @SerializedName("full_name")
    @Expose
    String name;

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    String email;

    @SerializedName("phone")
    @Expose
    String phone;

    @SerializedName("profile_image_url")
    @Expose
    String imageUrl;

    @SerializedName("service_type")
    @Expose
    int serviceType;

    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    String address;

    @SerializedName("area_detail")
    @Expose
    Place area_detail;

    @SerializedName("logitude")
    @Expose
    String longitude;

    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    String latitude;

    @SerializedName("startTime")
    @Expose
    String startTime;

    @SerializedName("endTime")
    @Expose
    String endTime;

    @SerializedName("menu")
    @Expose
    List<CookMenuResponse> menuResponseList;

    public List<CookMenuResponse> getMenuResponseList() {
        return menuResponseList;
    }

    public void setMenuResponseList(List<CookMenuResponse> menuResponseList) {
        this.menuResponseList = menuResponseList;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public int getServiceType() {
        return serviceType;
    }

    public void setServiceType(int serviceType) {
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Place getArea_detail() {
        return area_detail;
    }

    public void setArea_detail(Place area_detail) {
        this.area_detail = area_detail;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
}
```

This is where I am calling function

```
private void getCooksList() {
    RetrofitApi retrofitApi = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient().create(RetrofitApi.class);
    Log.i(" TAG FoodieHome check",""+jsonRequest.toString());
    retrofitApi.getCooksNearBy(jsonRequest.toString()).enqueue(new Callback<GetNearByCooks>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetNearByCooks> call, Response<GetNearByCooks> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                if (response.body().getStatus_code() == 200 && response.body().getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
                {
                    Log.i("TAG Response","in response");
                }
            }
            Log.i("TAG Response","in response\n"+response.body().getStatus()+"\n"+response.body().getStatus_code());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetNearByCooks> call, Throwable t) {
            refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            Log.i("TAG Response","in error response\n"+t.getCause());
        }
    });
}
```

Retrofit client

```
public class RetrofitClient {


  private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient()
    {
        if (retrofit == null)
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Config.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Finally here is my logcat result

```
I/ TAG FoodieHome check: {"device_type":"android","os_type":"android","os_version":"21","build_version":"1.0","token":"d86b6e42-c24d-4fc6-a0f9-565b0cf5f9b9","logitude":"74.23893","latitude":"31.454477","data":{"logitude":"74.23893","latitude":"31.454477","radius":20}}
I/TAG Response: in error response                                                                        java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Interface can't be instantiated! Interface name: com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place
```

This is my Gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.4'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0"
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a answer but you might want to obscure the "token" value in your logcat value.

Comment: Can you please post the CookDetails?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: post the import statements of `cookdetails`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer thanks for this comment I'll remember next time while asking questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CookDetails object you're using:

```
@SerializedName("area_detail")
@Expose
Place area_detail;
```

Gson doesn't know which object to instantiate as `Place` is an interface.

So create your own Place object:

```
public class MyPlace implements Place{
  // your implementation
}
```

Then in the CookDetails object do:

```
@SerializedName("area_detail")
@Expose
MyPlace area_detail;
```

Comment: If you don't need the info returned in the `area_detail` field, just remove it from CookDetails

Comment: Its google place Api object. What is the problem with this plus in same app i am sending place object while signing up which works fine

Comment: Place is NOT an object, it's an interface so it needs to be implemented to be instantiated. Idk how you use it somewhere else but in this particular case, Gson wants to instantiate it and... can't as it's not an object

Comment: Alright can you please tell me how to do that the Implementation part I've never done that before

Comment: Let me try I'll be back in a moment

Comment: yes that was the problem thanks I checked my code i wasn't using place object anywhere so i removed it and it worked fine